# Storing string in binary format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, column-types

Why page title are stored in binary format instead of char format in MediaWiki? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#page_title

`SELECT page_id, BINARY CONVERT(page_title USING utf8) as page_title ...`

Is there any advantage or general benefit?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson "Works with any character encoding " ?? Is there any thing wrong with storing char?

Comment: Ah, in your edit it shows that it encodes it in UTF8 anyway when encoding to binary... so the encoding thing is probably not a reason.

Comment: Otherwise, a char is not always the same, the encoding of it depends on the [character set encoding you're using](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html). UTF8 is almost always a good choice though, since it has most characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because MySQL's `utf8` collation doesn't support characters outside of [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) and `utf8mb4` which does was added only recently, in MySQL 5.5.3. And in MySQL's implementation "doesn't support" means "mangled text".

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add a link to show this is the only reason for that?